# Continue listening for SQLDependency

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqldependency

I have a Windows Form application that use a Notifier for capture SQLDependency change event with Entity Framework and all works fine. The EntityChangeNotifier is a project that elaborate the SQLDependency.

Whit the call `while (true)` i can have a continue listening and when i have a change the code enter in `notifer.Changed += (sender, e)`

```
        private StartNotifier()
        {
            var info = new SABIntegrationEntities();
            // Notifier
            using (var notifer = new EntityChangeNotifier<SpRicezioneSpedizioniLightNotifier, GemapDbContext>(p => p.SPEDIZIONE_STATO_GENERAZIONE == "I" || p.SPEDIZIONE_STATO_GENERAZIONE == "U"))
            {
                notifer.Error += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    Log.Error(String.Format("[{0}, {1}, {2}]:\n{3}", e.Reason.Info, e.Reason.Source, e.Reason.Type, e.Sql));
                };
                notifer.Changed += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    e.ContinueListening = false;
                    bool result = true;
                    var spedizioniI = info.SpRicezioneSpedizioniLights.Where(x => x.SPEDIZIONE_STATO_GENERAZIONE == "I" || x.SPEDIZIONE_STATO_GENERAZIONE == "U");
                    foreach (var p in spedizioniI)
                        {
                            p.SPEDIZIONE_STATO_GENERAZIONE = "G";
                        }
                    }
                    e.ContinueListening = true;
                };
                while (true)
                {
                }
           }
       }
```

I want to have a continue listening in this code better than While(true). How can i do it?

If you want you can find the complete project structure here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543328/invalid-statement-subscribe-in-sqldependency)

Thank to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using statement is disposing `notifer` when you exit `StartNotifier` method. Remove using and while statments, put `notifer` as private class field, implement `IDisposable` interface and dispose `notifer` in `Dispose` method. You should receive messages until your class containing `StartNotifier` method is not disposed.

EDIT: Code snippet to give you an idea:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly EntityChangeNotifier<SpRicezioneSpedizioniLightNotifier, GemapDbContext> _entityChangeNotifier;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _entityChangeNotifier = StartNotifier();
    }

    private EntityChangeNotifier<SpRicezioneSpedizioniLightNotifier, GemapDbContext> StartNotifier()
    {
        var notifer = new EntityChangeNotifier<SpRicezioneSpedizioniLightNotifier, GemapDbContext>(
            p => p.SPEDIZIONE_STATO_GENERAZIONE == "I" || p.SPEDIZIONE_STATO_GENERAZIONE == "U");
        notifer.Error += (sender, e) => { /*log*/ };
        notifer.Changed += (sender, e) => { /*action when chagned*/};
        return notifer;
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
            _entityChangeNotifier.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can i dispose the only notifier and reactivate a new notifier if I have an error?I want to restart the notifier automatically if i have same error in the listen.